# twisted web get host:port tuple in async response

Tags: python, twisted

I am able to make async requests using examples at:
http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/client.html

I can get the async responses inside Protocol.dataReceived() but how do I find out which response is mapped to which request? I would like to map the response I get back to the original host:port/request.

Also, is it safe to use global like I am doing here?

```
class ClientResponseProtocol(Protocol):

  def __init__(self, whenFinished):
      self.whenFinished = whenFinished

  def dataReceived(self, bytes):
    global BUILD_REVISION

    d = json.loads(bytes)
    bv = d.get("build_revision")

    if bv in BUILD_REVISION:
      BUILD_REVISION[bv] += 1
    else:
      BUILD_REVISION[bv] = 1

  def makeConnection(self, transport):
    pass

  def connectionLost(self, reason):
    self.whenFinished.callback(None)

def handleResponse(r):
  #print("version=%s\ncode=%s\nphrase='%s'" % (r.version, r.code, r.phrase))
  #for k,v in r.headers.getAllRawHeaders():
  #  print(k, v)
  finished = twisted.internet.defer.Deferred()
  r.deliverBody(ClientResponseProtocol(finished))
  return finished

def handleError(reason):
  reason.printTraceback()
  reactor.stop()

def getPage(url):
  d = Agent(reactor).request('GET', url, Headers({'User-Agent': ['user']}), None)
  d.addCallbacks(handleResponse, handleError)
  return d


semaphore = twisted.internet.defer.DeferredSemaphore(BATCH_SIZE)
dl = list()

for server in servers:
  dl.append(semaphore.run(getPage, 'http://%s/server_info.json' % server))

dl = twisted.internet.defer.DeferredList(dl)
dl.addCallbacks(lambda x: reactor.stop(), handleError)

reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass extra arguments to a `Deferred` callback:

```
d.addCallback(f, extra, positional, args, keyword=args)
```

So, for example:

```
def report_result(result, request_url):
    ...

url = 'http://%s/server_info.json' % server
d = getPage(url)
d.addCallback(report_result, request_url=url)
```

Or in a loop:

```
list_of_results = []
for server in list_of_servers:
    url = 'http://%s/server_info.json' % server
    d = getPage(url)
    d.addCallback(report_result, request_url=url)
    list_of_results.append(d)

all_requests = DeferredList(list_of_results)
...
```

Separately, you may also want to look at `twisted.web.client.Agent` to replace your use of `getPage`.

Comment: I have the responses goto the ClientResponseProtocol. I needed the url in that class so I can map the HTTP responses to the original request. Are these callback arguments available in there somewhere?

Comment: They're just more arguments.  You can pass them to anything you want to pass them to - including to `ClientResponseProtocol.__init__` if you like.

Answer (score 0):

- First of all, don't use globals. It is evil.
- Second, Twisted creates Protocol instance for every connection. So all the attributes that you will define in `Protocol.__init__()` will be "connection scoped".
- Third, every Protocol instance should be connected with transport, that describes connection (tcp, for example). Transport object contains data that you need, it could be retrieved like this:

> ```
> def makeConnection(self, transport):
>     # for a TransportProxyProducer
>     host = transport._producer.getPeer().host
>     port = transport._producer.getPeer().port
> ```

Here is some links for api docs that may help:

- http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.0/api/twisted.internet.address.IPv4Address.html

Comment: That didn't work. I added more of the code for context. The only transport (TransportProxyProducer) variable I have is inside makeConnection() and that doesn't seem to contain the getPeer().

Comment: exceptions.AttributeError: 'TransportProxyProducer' object has no attribute 'producer'. This is a Protocol class, should these be in there?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I've updated my answer one more time, `transport._producer` should be instead of `transport.producer`